# Weird monitor glitch looking like camcorder

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, displayport

So randomly I started noticing a weird glitch on my [Asus VA32AQ](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Monitors/VA32AQ/). Basically I got these thin translucent lines on my monitor. There only really visible on bright and colourful things. Here's an [example](https://s3.envato.com/files/1435676/recording%20preview%20590x300.jpg) of what it looks like (minus the text and recording icon). Anyone know what I can do?

**Additional info:**

Using DisplayPort

Windows 10 build 17074

Tried updating to latest drivers, nothing

Removed GPU and ran integrated graphics. Nothing.

Interestingly, this only happens on my main monitor.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBnb1.jpg) a picture I took with my phone. You can't really see it in a picture.

**Edit:**

Tested with Xbox, still looks the same. It's a glitch with the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off VIVID PIXEL.
Menu > Image > VividPixel and set it to 0

From what I can gather from other users of this monitor, this can cause some artifacting problems.

Comment: Vivid pixel is at 0